# Commits to GitHub repo showing large quantities of unintentional changes

Tags: xcode, git, github

I've been commiting/pushing to a public repo and finding that one commit where I may have changed less than 100 lines results in a commit with 1000 changes.

For example, I may change several lines in a method in AppDelegate.
The resulting problem is something that looks like that following:

[image]

To better showoff what whitespace issues might be occurring here is another area of unwanted commitage:

[image]

Comment: Are you running any code formatting tools? Looks like these changes in the screenshot are whitespace being removed from the beginning of each comment line.

Comment: i don't know what you mean by formatted my code.  One thing I may have done that the coder who last worked on appdelegate was hit Ctrl+i which does auto-indent and such.  is that what you mean by format?

Comment: Yes, auto-indent will "clean" up whitespace and tabs that it deems need fixing. Auto-indent is just one facet of code formatting that can be done on demand (in this case by keyboard shortcut) or automatically with a tool. Regardless, git tracks all the content of the file, so when you change even a space, it shows up in a diff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have formatted the code and now git treats your whitecaps as changes.

Set this flag to ignore any white spaces changes

> ***`core.whitespace`***
>
> Git comes preset to detect and fix some whitespace issues.
>   It can look for six primary whitespace issues – three are enabled by default and can be turned off, and three are disabled by default but can be activated.

```
git config --global core.whitespace <...>
```

---

## ***`core.whitespace`***

> ***`core.whitespace`***
>
> A comma separated list of common whitespace problems to notice. `git diff` will use `color.diff.whitespace` to highlight them, and git apply --whitespace=error will consider them as errors.
>
> You can prefix `-` to disable any of them (e.g. -trailing-space):
>
> ***blank-at-eol***
>    treats trailing whitespaces at the end of the line as an error (enabled by default).
>
> ***space-before-tab***
>    treats a space character that appears immediately before a tab character in the initial indent part of the line as an error (enabled by default).
>
> ***indent-with-non-tab***
>   treats a line that is indented with space characters instead of the equivalent tabs as an error (not enabled by default).
>
> ***tab-in-indent***
>   treats a tab character in the initial indent part of the line as an error (not enabled by default).
>
> ***blank-at-eof***
>   treats blank lines added at the end of file as an error (enabled by default).
>
> trailing-space is a short-hand to cover both blank-at-eol and blank-at-eof.
>
> ***cr-at-eol treats***
>   a carriage-return at the end of line as part of the line terminator, i.e. with it, trailing-space does not trigger if the character before such a carriage-return is not a whitespace (not enabled by default).
>
> ***tabwidth=***
>    tells how many character positions a tab occupies; this is relevant for indent-with-non-tab and when Git fixes tab-in-indent errors. The default tab width is 8. Allowed values are 1 to 63

Comment: so looking at those comments in the appDelegate methods, it seems like space-before-tab may be the git property to address it? (yet the space occurs before the first "//" and not before the tab which would presumably be at the front of the line).

so the git command to ignore (i assume this is what the documentation you listed means by error?) these white spaces would be as follows?
git config --global core.whitespace <space-before-tab>

Comment: Its hard to tell from the image since there can be tabs set to 2 spaces, simple 2 spaces, your editor can convert tabs to spaces and vice versa so you simply have to try it out.

Comment: i added another picture to my post.

Comment: can this be done only for a repo and not globally?

Comment: Yep, set the configuration as `--local`. `git config --local core.whitespace <...>`